# Проблема с импортом модулей в Django: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

у меня возникают проблемы с импортом модулей из одного Django-приложения в другое. Моя структура проекта выглядит следующим образом:

```
D:\Project\
    - Project\
        - main_page\
        - users_registration\
            - __init__.py
            - backend\
                - __init__.py
                - django_registration\              (это джанго-приложение для бэкенда)
                    - __init__.py
                    - models.py
                    - другие файлы

    - другие_приложения\
    - manage.py
```

Мне нужно импортировать модель `UserInfo` из `models.py` приложения `django_registration` в приложение `django_main` `D:\Project\Project\main_page\backend\django_main\models.py`. Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
from users_registration.backend.django_registration.models import UserInfo
```

Однако, при попытке импортировать модель, я получаю ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users_registration'`.

Вот, собственно, файл `models.py` из которого мне нужно импортировать `D:\Project\Project\users_registration\backend\django_registration\models.py`. И часть кода:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
```

Я перепроверил свои пути, а также `INSTALLED_APPS` - все безошибочно, также я добавил в каждую подпапку файл `__init__.py`, я ума не приложу, в чем может быть причина.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'users_registration.backend.django_registration',

    'main_page.backend.django_main',
     и тп
]
```

Могли бы вы мне пожалуйста помочь разобраться, почему возникает эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Питон ищет модули в папках указаных в переменной окружения `PYTHONPATH`. При старте приложения нужно чтоб в `PYTHONPATH` был путь `D:\Project\Project`